# App doesn't connect or Firebase authentication doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Just today I was able to run my app without logical errors, but it has a login connected with Firebase authentication, but the latter stores the record or logs in to enter.

It gives me this information when I register

```
WARN Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 5):

Error: Something went wrong!

http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:105618:28
generatorResume@[native code]

asyncGeneratorStep@http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:20663:26
_next@http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:20682:29
tryCallOne@http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:25276:16
http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:25357:27
http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:26252:26
_callTimer@http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:26171:17
_callReactNativeMicrotasksPass@http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:26201:17
callReactNativeMicrotasks@http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:26364:44
__callReactNativeMicrotasks@http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:19801:46
http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:19613:45
__guard@http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:19785:15
flushedQueue@http://192.168.199.154:19000/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:19612:21
flushedQueue@[native code]

callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue@[native code]
```

The login is with redux and in the action is connected the connection with firebase authentication and the startup file (welcome)

```
/* eslint-disable no-case-declarations */
import { useState, useReducer } from 'react';
import { View, Button, TouchableOpacity, Text, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform,Image } from 'react-native';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { styles } from './styles';
import { Input, } from '../../components';
import Colors  from '../../constants/color';
import { signIn, signUp } from '../../store/actions';
import { UPDATED_FORM, onInputChange } from '../../utils/forms';

const initialState = {
  email: { value: '', error: '', touched: false, hasError: true },
  password: { value: '', error: '', touched: false, hasError: true },
  isFormValid: false,
};

const formReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATED_FORM:
      const { name, value, hasError, error, touched, isFormValid } = action.data;
      return {
        ...state,
        [name]: {
          ...state[name],
          value,
          hasError,
          error,
          touched,
        },
        isFormValid,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const Welcome = ({ navigation }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(true);
  const [formState, dispatchFormState] = useReducer(formReducer, initialState);
  const title = isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Register';
  const message = isLogin ? "Don't have an account?" : 'Already have an account?';
  const messageButton = isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Register';

  const onHandlerSubmit = () => {
    dispatch(
      isLogin
        ? signIn(formState.email.value, formState.password.value)
        : signUp(formState.email.value, formState.password.value)
    );
  };

  const onHandlerInputChange = (value, type) => {
    onInputChange(type, value, dispatchFormState, formState);
  };
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      style={styles.keybordContainer}
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'height' : 'padding'}
      enabled>
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={require("../../../assets/logos.png")} />
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
          <Input
            placeholder="enter your email"
            placeholderTextColor={Colors.gray}
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            onChangeText={(text) => onHandlerInputChange(text, 'email')}
            value={formState.email.value}
            hasError={formState.email.hasError}
            error={formState.email.error}
            touched={formState.email.touched}
            label="Email"
            labelStyle={styles.label}
          />
          <Input
            placeholder="enter your password"
            placeholderTextColor={Colors.gray}
            secureTextEntry
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            onChangeText={(text) => onHandlerInputChange(text, 'password')}
            value={formState.password.value}
            hasError={formState.password.hasError}
            error={formState.password.error}
            touched={formState.password.touched}
            label="Password"
            labelStyle={styles.label}
          />
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button title={messageButton} color={Colors.primary} onPress={onHandlerSubmit} />
            <View style={styles.prompt}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.promptButton} onPress={() => setIsLogin(!isLogin)}>
                <Text style={styles.promptMessage}>{message}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <Image style={styles.foot} source={require("../../../assets/pielogo.png")} />
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default Welcome;
```

Action:

```
import { URL_AUTH_SIGN_IN, URL_AUTH_SIGN_UP } from '../../constants/firebase';
import { userTypes } from '../types';

const { SIGN_UP, SIGN_IN } = userTypes;

export const signUp = (email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL_AUTH_SIGN_UP, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password,
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Something went wrong!');
      }

      const data = await response.json();

      dispatch({
        type: SIGN_UP,
        token: data.idToken,
        userId: data.localId,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
};

export const signIn = (email, password) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(URL_AUTH_SIGN_IN, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password,
          returnSecureToken: true,
        }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      dispatch({
        type: SIGN_IN,
        token: data.idToken,
        userId: data.localId,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
};
```

Can you explain to me why and how to solve this error, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`catch` statements are catching `throw` why you throw error inside catch statement? Change it to `console.log()` or however you want to handle error, but not throw it again.